# How do I pan an image in Lightroom while using the adjustment brush?

Tags: lightroom

Is there any keyboard control for panning, or something similar to -mouse to pan while I'm using the adjustment brush?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just hold down the space bar and drag with the mouse.

Comment: :) It's actually a pretty common shortcut - it works in Photoshop and a few other programs too.